# Magento 2 | deploy static content error

Tags: magento-2.1, css, less, static-content, static-content-deploy

I got this error when running **`setup:static-content:deploy`** on **Magento 2.1.8**:

```
Compilation from source: /microcloud/domains/vampm2/domains/mydomains.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less

Compilation from source:
frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/en_GB/css/styles-m.less
variable @checkout-step-content-mobile__background is undefined in file /microcloud/domains/vampm2/domains/mydomain.co.uk/http/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_shipping.less in _shipping.less on line 213, column 34
211|         .form-shipping-address,
212|         .methods-shipping {
213|             .lib-css(background, @checkout-step-content-mobile__background);
214|             .lib-css(margin, @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin);
215|             .lib-css(padding, @indent__base @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin-s);
 in _responsive.less
```

This is a `.less` file form `/vampm2/domains/mydomian.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_shipping.less`:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__s) {
    .opc-wrapper {
        .form-login,
        .form-shipping-address,
        .methods-shipping {
            .lib-css(background, @checkout-step-content-mobile__background);
            .lib-css(margin, @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin);
            .lib-css(padding, @indent__base @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin-s);
        }
```

---

**UPDATE** The variable is not defined within this file. There are variables defined at the top of this page but `checkout-step-content-mobile__background` is not. From comments below, the `checkout-step-content-mobile__background` variable is defined in the `_checkout.less` file and I have found the declaration only in the `http\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\checkout\_checkout.less` but from what the `system.log` say's, it's trying to pull it from **`theme-frontend-blank`**:

```
[2017-12-14 12:24:08] main.CRITICAL: Compilation from source: /microcloud/domains/vampm2/domains/operationvape.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
```

---

***UPDATE***

Here is the error from my `system.log`:

```
[2017-12-14 12:24:08] main.CRITICAL: 
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/en_US/css/styles-m.less
variable @checkout-step-content-mobile__background is undefined in file /microcloud/domains/vampm2/domains/operationvape.co.uk/http/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/checkout/_shipping.less in _shipping.less on line 213, column 34
211|         .form-shipping-address,
212|         .methods-shipping {
213|             .lib-css(background, @checkout-step-content-mobile__background);
214|             .lib-css(margin, @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin);
215|             .lib-css(padding, @indent__base @checkout-step-content-mobile__margin-s);
216|         }
 in _responsive.less [] []
[2017-12-14 12:24:08] main.CRITICAL: Compilation from source: /microcloud/domains/vampm2/domains/operationvape.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
```

Comment: You should have either a vars.less or variables.less file along with your other less files. Open it and make sure `@checkout-step-content-mobile__background` is defined and has a value assigned to it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the path the file correctly. See updated question now. The code snippet is from `_shipping.less` file. There is no `vars.less` or `variables.less` files in the same directory or anywhere within the `Magento_Checkout` directory :/

Comment: Are the other variables called within that file defined within the _shipping.less file itself? If you have to, just define it above where it is called. So you would just do: `@checkout-step-content-mobile__background: #ffffff;` and replace the `ffffff` string with a color of your choice.

Comment: Looking at that file in my local build, it looks like all the var's are declared at the top of the _shipping.less file. Add the undefined one in with them, and you should be good to go.

Comment: That variable is definied in the _checkout.less file, I'm not sure why you are getting the error while compiling unless that file has been overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I do have variables declarations at the top of the file but the mention variable is not declared. What is the location of your `_checkout.less`? I can't find it for some reason :/ I think it might be because I have changed the theme to the `cricket_child` as I didn't see this error before.

Comment: I found `@checkout-step-content-mobile__background: @color-gray-light01;` in `http\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\checkout\_checkout.less`. Since, I am using custom theme, do I have to declare it again somewhere? That the only location of the `checkout-step-content-mobile__background` that's left in my whole Magento install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at the answer from @Suresh R, it's not ideal to set the permissions to 777.

Magento recommends all directories to have 770 permissions and all files have 660 permissions.

To achieve the following run the command:

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux os please use this command to deploy the content go to your root folder of your project and give this command in your terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var && sudo chmod -R 777 pub && sudo chmod -R 777 generated  && sudo php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade  && sudo chmod -R 777 var && sudo chmod -R 777 pub && sudo chmod -R 777 generated && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && sudo chmod -R 777 var && sudo chmod -R 777 pub && sudo chmod -R 777 generated
```

Comment: 777 permissions are not the best idea, see correct persmissions from Magento documentation